# How to Call on WordPress Custom Fields without a Plugin

Tags: php, custom-field

I have two custom fields created for pages, not posts, in WordPress. How can I display the values of these custom fields in a block editor, such as Elementor, without the use of a plugin like ACF? I've read many articles with directions on placing custom code in either the functions.php, single.php, or page.php. However, there are no directions on how to call upon these custom fields within the content.

Here is what I would like to do:

- Add a custom field to a page using native WordPress custom fields
- Display this custom field anywhere I want to on a page using a shortcode

Comment: Most custom fields, plugin or not, is accessible via [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's what all the articles say but I need a bit more help and direction with getting this to work.

Comment: Could you edit your question with what it is you're trying to accomplish please? I'm unsure if you have a shortcode you're trying to create or if you're trying to create a Block in the Block Editor or if you're wanting to create some custom functionality for a 3rd party plugin ( which would be considered off-topic and better asked via their support forums/methods ). What code have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? Could you be a bit more specific on what it is you don't understand in the tutorials you've followed?

Comment: Sure thing. I added a little bit to the question. It's very simple what I'm trying to do.